# Cannot access ViewModel method from fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

Probably it has a simple solution that I cant see. I have a fragment with a ViewModel, The Viewmodel has a method inside of it that I want to call from my fragment and supply the arguments for. but when I try to call the method it shows an error "Unsolved Reference"

```
 class DetailFragmentViewModel : ViewModel() {

       private val repo = Crepository.get()
       private val itemIdlivedata = MutableLiveData<UUID>()
       var crimeLiveDate: LiveData<Crime?> = Transformations.switchMap(itemIdlivedata){ it -> 
       repo.getitem(it) }
    fun LoadItem(itemuuid:UUID){
     itemIdlivedata.value = itemuuid
                          }
                  }
```

Fragment Class:

```
  private val crimeDetailVM : ViewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProvider(this).get(DetailFragmentViewModel::class.java)
}
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     ...

   crimeDetailVM.LoadItem <- Unsolved Reference 

}
```

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:IT HAS A SIMPLE SOLUTION, I DID NOT CAST THE VIEW MODEL TO THE VIEW MODEL CLASS,THANKS FOR THE HELP EVERYONE**

Comment: Aren't you providing an argument to the function? `crimeDetailVM.LoadItem(myUUID)`. Or did you just omit it for brevity?

Comment: @Beko I want to call LoadItem() from the fragment,then Loaditem will pull the livedata out of the repository, so i can observe it in the fragment, I dont know why i cannot access the method

Comment: @Beko thanks, but that is not the cause of the problem,even with arguments it cant find the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing **downcasting** DetailFragmentViewModel to ViewModel. That is why you are not accessing to DetailFragmentViewModel methods.

Use

```
private val crimeDetailVM : DetailFragmentViewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProvider(this).get(DetailFragmentViewModel::class.java)
}
```

Instead of

```
private val crimeDetailVM : ViewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProvider(this).get(DetailFragmentViewModel::class.java)
}
```

Also this way is not idiomatic i suggest you to use kotlin extension

```
val viewModel by viewModels<DetailFragmentViewModel>()
```

But before do that you need to add the dependency which is Fragment KTX to your app gradle file.

https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx

Answer (score 0):

You need activity context
try:
ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(DetailFragmentViewModel::class.java)

you can use also extend view model by ActivityViewModel
eg.->   class DetailFragmentViewModel(application:Application) : AndroidViewModel(applivation){}